# JQuery how do I add new divs using .load?

Tags: php, jquery

This replaces the content in #message_here, each time. How do I get it to keep adding the content, by creating new divs for each message?

```
  var last_mess_id = 1;
  $('#load_mess').click(function(){      
      $('#messages_here').load('ajax/get_message.php?last_mess_id='+last_mess_id);
      last_mess_id++;
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `$.get()` function instead, and during the callback function you specify `function(data) { $('#messages_here').append(data); }`

http://api.jquery.com/get/

`.load()` is meant to replace the content of the specified element, so avoid using that. http://api.jquery.com/load/